# Filtering a list of lists based on a variable number of combinations in Netlogo

Tags: list, netlogo

Suppose I have a list of lists I want to filter. The list is such that, in each element, the first two strings are the contents
I want to keep, the third number is the number of times it should appear in the filtered list, and the
last element is the value of the list determining what particular combination appears. 
The idea is to keep only the n most valuable items of each, where n is the third element of each list inside, and the value is
determined by the last entry, but also, if there are less combinations than the third item, keep as many as possible.

Thus, in the example below, I would like to have only the first "a", "b" combination, keep the first two "a" "c" ones, 
and retain the last, (even though there is no further "a" "d" combinations in it):

I have been trying to use several combinations of filter and thought about ways to retain list elements, 
without success for this particular problem.

```
to setup
let temp-example []
set temp-example [["a" "b" 1 5] ["a" "b" 1 3] ["a" "c" 2 4] ["a" "c" 2 2] 
["a" "c" 2 1] ["a" "d" 4 1]]
end
```

Desired output is the following list:

```
[["a" "b" 1 5]["a" "c" 2 4]["a" "c" 2 2] ["a" "d" 4 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure one of the heavyweights around here will chime in soon with a one-or-two line solution, but for now I think this does what you're after. With these reporters:

```
to-report multifilter [ list_ ]
  ; Get the content pairs
  let content-pairs remove-duplicates map [ i -> sublist i 0 2 ] list_

  ; Reorganize list into sublists for each content pair
  let by-content-pairs map [ i -> filter [ j -> sublist j 0 2 = i ] list_ ] content-pairs

  ; Sort the sublists
  let sorted-by-value map [ i -> sort-with 3 i ] by-content-pairs

  ; Keep only first n items of each sublist,
  report reduce sentence map [ i -> keep-n 2 i ] sorted-by-value
end

to-report sort-with [ ind lst ]
  ; Sort the sublists by one of their indexed values
  report sort-by [ [ a b ] -> ( item ind a ) > ( item ind b ) ] lst
end

to-report keep-n [ ind lst ]
  ; Keep only as many values as are passed by ind, or the length
  ; of the list, whichever value is smaller
  let n item ind first lst
  if n > length lst [
    set n length lst
  ]
  report sublist lst 0 n
end
```

Call `multifilter` on a list with the format you've shown and you should get your desired output:

```
to filter-multi
  let temp-example [
    ["a" "b" 1 5] ["a" "b" 1 3] ["a" "c" 2 1]
    ["a" "c" 2 4] ["a" "c" 2 2] ["a" "d" 4 1]
  ]

  print multifilter temp-example
end
```

Output:

```
[[a b 1 5] [a c 2 4] [a c 2 2] [a d 4 1]]
```

Another example:

```
to filter-multi
  let temp-example [
    ["a" "b" 1 31] ["a" "b" 1 15] ["a" "b" 1 -53] ["a" "b" 1 10] ["a" "b" 1 3000]
    ["a" "c" 2 1] ["a" "c" 2 4] ["a" "c" 2 2] ["a" "c" 2 -10] ["a" "c" 2 14] ["a" "c" 2 40]
    ["a" "d" 4 1] ["a" "d" 4 12]
  ]

  print multifilter temp-example
end
```

Output:

```
[[a b 1 3000] [a c 2 40] [a c 2 14] [a d 4 12] [a d 4 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm!    I was trying things out and got more or less halfway before throwing my hands into the air in despair  I will also follow your advice and wait a little bit more, as well as try to implement a shorter version, before finally accepting your answer. Many thanks again! 

Answer (score 0):

I think this more or less answers it as well:

```
to-report frequency [an-item a-list]
    report length (filter [ i -> i = an-item] a-list)
end

; Reporter to keep the n most valuable combinations
to-report take [n xs]
  report sublist xs 0 min list n (length xs)
end

to go
  set temp-1[]
  set temp-2[]
  set temp-3[]
  set temp-4[]
  foreach temp-example[[i] ->
    set temp-1 lput (list item 0 i item 1 i) temp-1
  set temp-2 lput item 2 i temp-2]
    foreach temp-1[[j] ->
      set temp-3 lput frequency j temp-1 temp-3
    ]
  ;First: obtain all existing combinations between the two letters:
  foreach (range 0 (length temp-example)) [[j]->
    ifelse item j temp-2 <= item j temp-3 [set temp-4 lput take (item j temp-2) 
filter [i -> (list item 0 i item 1 i) = item j temp-1] temp-example temp-4];
     [set temp-4 lput item j temp-example temp-4]; caso contrario, colocar so ate aos 
item 2 j:
  ]
  show remove-duplicates temp-4
end
```